# Soql not queried the requested field error but i am querying the field

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql, error

Class:

```
public void PNSearch(){
    //varible declarations
    parentId=Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
    //Query to retrieve all Quote line Items which are childs to current Quote
    list< Quote_line_Item__c> allQliList=[Select id,Name,Client_P_N__c,Comments__c,Quote1__r.Quoteopp_record_type__c,Quote1__r.Quoteopp_type__c,Quote1__c,Quote_Validity__c ,Description__c,Standard_Estimated_Lead_Time__c,createdDate,Other_Lead_Time__c  from Quote_Line_Item__c where Quote1__c=:parentId ORDER BY CreatedDate ] ;

    set<string> qliNameSet =new set<string>();
    List<String> qliNameList=new List<String>();
    list<Quote_line_Item__c> matchQliList=new list<Quote_line_Item__c>();
    List<Quote__c> QuoteList=new List<Quote__c>();
    Set<Id> nonMatchedQutIds=new Set<Id>();
    Set<id> QlId=new Set<Id>();
    Quote__c currentQuote;
    //creating instance to wrpper classes
    QuoteWrapperListTwo=new List<QuoteWrapperTwo>();
    QuoteWrapperListOne=new List<QuoteWrapperOne>();
    QuoteWrapperList=new List<QuoteWrapper>();
    // Declaring and creating instance to map
    map<id,List<Quote_line_Item__c>> allMatchedQlis= new map<id,List<Quote_line_Item__c>>();
    try{
        currentQuote=[select Account_Name__r.Name,id from Quote__c where id=:ParentId LIMIT 1];
    }catch(Exception e){System.debug('<----Quote exception------>'+e); }
    //condition to check quote lIne item  map size is greater than zero
    if(allQliList.size()>0){
        //iterating the loop to store the name quote line items in list and in set
        for(Quote_line_Item__c qli:allQliList){
            qliNameSet.add(qli.Name);
            qliNameList.add(qli.Name);
        }//End of for loop
        // Query to get all quoteline items  which are matched with current Quote line items names
        try{
            matchQliList=[Select id,Name,Quote1__r.Quote_Number_New__c,Quote1__r.Quoteopp_record_type__c,Quote1__r.Opportunity_Name__r.Name,Quote1__r.Opportunity_Name__c,Quote1__r.Quoteopp_type__c,Quote1__r.Account_Name__c,Quote1__r.Account_Name__r.Name,Quote1__r.createdDate,Quote1__r.Name,Quote1__c from Quote_line_Item__c where Quote1__c!=:ParentId And Name in:qliNameSet];
        }catch(Exception e){ system.debug('<----Quote line item exception--------- >'+e);}
        //Iterating the loop to store the Quote ids in to the set
        for(Quote_line_Item__c q:matchQliList){
            QlId.add(q.Quote1__c);
        }
        //Query to get all quoteline items  which are matched with current Quote line items names
        try{
            QuoteList=[Select id,Quote_Number_New__c,Quote__c.Quoteopp_type__c,Quote__c.Quoteopp_record_type__c,Opportunity_Name__r.name,Opportunity_Name__c,Account_Name__c,Account_Name__r.Name,createdDate,(select id,Name,Quote1__r.Quote_Number_New__c,Quote1__r.Account_Name__c,Quote1__r.Account_Name__r.Name,Quote1__r.createdDate,Quote1__r.Name from Quote__c.Quote_line_Items__r) from Quote__c where id in:QlId ORDER BY CreatedDate  desc LIMIT 50000];
        }catch(Exception e){ System.debug('<***** Quote line item exception****>'+e);}
        //Iterating the loop to place the quote line items in a map with key as Quote id and value as quoteline items
        for(Quote__c qut:QuoteList){
            List<Quote_line_Item__c> qliList=new List<Quote_line_Item__c>();
            for(Quote_line_Item__c ql:qut.Quote_line_Items__r){
                qliList.add(ql);
            }//End of for loop
            allMatchedQlis.put(qut.id,qliList);
        }//End of for loop
        //iterating the map to seperate the Quote values which have exact match with the current quote and non exact quotes
        for(Id mapkey:allMatchedQlis.keyset()){
            String accName=allMatchedQlis.get(mapkey)[0].Quote1__r.Account_Name__r.Name;
            List<String> dupQliNameList=new List<String>();
            //Iterating the loop to store all the Quoteline item's names for each quote
            for(Quote_line_Item__c qli:allMatchedQlis.get(mapkey)){
                dupQliNameList.add(qli.Name);
            }//End of for loop
            // sorting the lists which helps us to compare the current QUote line item name with other Quote child Quotelineitem's name
            dupQliNameList.sort();
            qliNameList.sort();
            //condition to check for exact match
            if(qliNameList.equals(dupQliNameList)&& allMatchedQlis.get(mapkey).size()==qliNameList.size()){
                // condition to check with the current account name and Adding values to display exact match with same accont
                if(accName==currentQuote.Account_Name__r.Name && mapkey!=ParentId){
                    QuoteWrapperTwo qwt=new QuoteWrapperTwo();
                    qwt.Quote_Name_Two=allMatchedQlis.get(mapkey)[0].Quote1__r.Name;
                    qwt.Quote_Id_Two=allMatchedQlis.get(mapkey)[0].Quote1__c;
                    qwt.Account_Name_Two=accName;
                    qwt.Account_Id_Two=allMatchedQlis.get(mapkey)[0].Quote1__r.Account_Name__c;
                    qwt.OPPtype_Two=allMatchedQlis.get(mapkey)[0].Quote1__r.Quoteopp_type__c;
                    qwt.OPPrecordtype_Two=allMatchedQlis.get(mapkey)[0].Quote1__r.Quoteopp_record_type__c;
                    qwt.OPPname_Two=allMatchedQlis.get(mapkey)[0].Quote1__r.Opportunity_Name__r.Name;
                    qwt.OPPid_Two=allMatchedQlis.get(mapkey)[0].Quote1__r.Opportunity_Name__c;
                    qwt.Quote_Num_Two=allMatchedQlis.get(mapkey)[0].Quote1__r.Quote_Number_New__c;
                    qwt.Count_Two=qliNameList.size();
                    qwt.CR_Date_Two=Date.valueOf(allMatchedQlis.get(mapkey)[0].Quote1__r.CreatedDate);
                    QuoteWrapperListTwo.add(qwt);
                }//End of if
                //Adding values to display exact match with different accont
                else{
                    QuoteWrapperOne qwt=new QuoteWrapperOne();
                    qwt.Quote_Name_One=allMatchedQlis.get(mapkey)[0].Quote1__r.Name;
                    qwt.Quote_Id_One=allMatchedQlis.get(mapkey)[0].Quote1__c;
                    qwt.Account_Name_One=accName;
                    qwt.Account_Id_One=allMatchedQlis.get(mapkey)[0].Quote1__r.Account_Name__c;
                    qwt.Quote_Num_One=allMatchedQlis.get(mapkey)[0].Quote1__r.Quote_Number_New__c;
                    qwt.OPPtype_one=allMatchedQlis.get(mapkey)[0].Quote1__r.Quoteopp_type__c;
                    qwt.OPPrecordtype_one=allMatchedQlis.get(mapkey)[0].Quote1__r.Quoteopp_record_type__c;
                    qwt.OPPname_one=allMatchedQlis.get(mapkey)[0].Quote1__r.Opportunity_Name__r.Name;
                    qwt.OPPid_one=allMatchedQlis.get(mapkey)[0].Quote1__r.Opportunity_Name__c;
                    qwt.Count_One=qliNameList.size();
                    qwt.CR_Date_One=Date.valueOf(allMatchedQlis.get(mapkey)[0].Quote1__r.CreatedDate);
                    QuoteWrapperListOne.add(qwt);
                }
            }//End of if
            //Storing non exact matched quote ids into a set
            else {
                nonMatchedQutIds.add(mapkey);
            }
        }//End of for loop
        //Query to get the Quote values in descending order depending on the counting of Quotelineitem names  which are in non exact match
        AggregateResult[] groupedResults   = [SELECT   COUNT_DISTINCT(Name) nameCount,count( Id ) idCount  ,MIN(Quote1__r.Quoteopp_record_type__c) OPPrecordtype ,MIN(Quote1__r.Quoteopp_type__c) OPPtype,MIN(Quote1__r.Opportunity_Name__c)  oppid, Min (Quote1__r.Opportunity_Name__r.Name) OPPname , Min( Quote1__r.Name  )   QuoteName  ,Min( Quote1__c  )   QuoteId  ,Min( Quote1__r.Account_Name__r.Name ) AccountName, Min( Quote1__r.Account_Name__c ) AccountId ,Min(Quote1__r.Quote_Number_New__c)QuoteNum, MIN(Quote1__r.CreatedDate) CRDate  FROM Quote_Line_Item__c  where   ( name in :qliNameSet  AND Quote1__c != null AND  Quote1__c in :nonMatchedQutIds)  Group By Quote1__r.Id ORDER BY COUNT_DISTINCT(Name) desc, MIN(Quote1__r.CreatedDate)desc];
        //Iterating the loop to display non exact matched quotes
        for(AggregateResult aggr:groupedResults){
            QuoteWrapper qw=new QuoteWrapper();
            qw.Quote_Name=String.valueOf(aggr.get('QuoteName'));
            qw.Quote_Id=String.valueOf(aggr.get('QuoteId'));
            qw.Account_Name=String.valueOf(aggr.get('AccountName'));
            qw.Account_Id=String.valueOf(aggr.get('AccountId'));
            qw.Quote_Num=String.valueOf(aggr.get('QuoteNum'));
            qw.Count=Integer.valueOf(aggr.get('nameCount'));
            qw.CR_Date=Date.valueOf(aggr.get('CRDate'));
            qw.oppid=String.valueOf(aggr.get('oppid'));
            qw.OPPtype=String.valueOf(aggr.get('OPPtype'));
            qw.OPPrecordtype=String.valueOf(aggr.get('OPPrecordtype'));
            qw.oppname=String.valueOf(aggr.get('oppname'));
            QuoteWrapperList.add(qw);
        }//End of for loop
    }//End of if
}//End of method
```

Vf page:

```
<apex:outputPanel id="panel"  >
            <div id="output1"></div>
            <div id="overlay1" class="web_dialog_overlay1"></div>
            <div id="dialog1" class="web_dialog1">
                <table style="width: 100%; border: 0px;" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0">
                    <tr>            
                        <td class="web_dialog_title align_right1" colspan="8" >
                        <apex:commandbutton value="cancel" action="{!cancel1}" id="cancelId" immediate="True"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>      
                        <td width="20%" colspan="8"><b>Similar Nicomatic P/N : </b></td>            
                        </tr>
                        <tr>      
                        <td width="20%" colspan="8"><hr/></td>            
                    </tr> 
                    <tr>
                        <td><b>SF Quote No</b></td>
                        <td><b>NCM Quote No</b></td>
                        <td><b>Account Number</b></td>
                        <td><b>Opportunity Name</b></td>
                        <td><b>Opportunity Record Type</b></td>
                        <td><b>Opportunity Type</b></td>
                        <td><b>Created Date</b></td>
                        <td><b>Maximum Match </b></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr><td colspan="8"><hr/></td></tr> 
                    <tr><td colspan="8"><b>Exact match with same Account</b></td></tr>
                    <apex:repeat value="{!QuoteWrapperListTwo}" var="a" > 
                        <tr> 
                            <td valign="top" width="20%"><a href="/{!a.Quote_Id_Two}" target="_blank">{!a.Quote_Name_Two}</a></td> 
                            <td valign="top" width="20%"><a href="/{!a.Quote_Id_Two}" target="_blank">{!a.Quote_Num_Two}</a></td> 
                            <td valign="top" width="20%"><a href="/{!a.Account_Id_Two}" target="_blank">{!a.Account_Name_Two}</a></td> 
                                <td valign="top" width="20%"><a href="/{!a.oppid_two}" target="_blank">{!a.oppname_two}</a></td>             
                            <td valign="top" width="20%">{!a.OPPrecordtype_two}</td> 
                            <td valign="top" width="20%">{!a.OPPtype_two}</td>             
                            <td valign="top" width="20%">    
                            <apex:outputText value="{0,date,dd'/'MM'/'yyyy}">
                            <apex:param value="{!a.CR_Date_Two}"/>
                            </apex:outputText>         
                            </td>
                            <td valign="top" width="20%" align="center" color="RED"><b>{!a.Count_Two}</b> 
                            </td> 
                        </tr>
                    </apex:repeat>
                    <tr><td colspan="8"><hr/></td></tr>       
                    <tr><td colspan="8"><b>Exact match with Other Account</b></td></tr>
                    <apex:repeat value="{!QuoteWrapperListOne}" var="a" > 
                        <tr> 
                            <td valign="top" width="20%"><a href="/{!a.Quote_Id_One}" target="_blank">{!a.Quote_Name_One}</a></td> 
                            <td valign="top" width="20%"><a href="/{!a.Quote_Id_One}" target="_blank">{!a.Quote_Num_One}</a></td> 
                            <td valign="top" width="20%"><a href="/{!a.Account_Id_One}" target="_blank">{!a.Account_Name_One}</a></td>
                                <td valign="top" width="20%"><a href="/{!a.oppid_one}" target="_blank">{!a.oppname_one}</a></td>             
                            <td valign="top" width="20%">{!a.OPPrecordtype_one}</td> 
                            <td valign="top" width="20%">{!a.OPPtype_one}</td>              
                            <td valign="top" width="20%">    
                            <apex:outputText value="{0,date,dd'/'MM'/'yyyy}">
                            <apex:param value="{!a.CR_Date_One}"/>
                            </apex:outputText>         
                            </td>
                            <td valign="top" width="20%" align="center" color="RED"><b>{!a.Count_One}</b> 
                            </td>            
                        </tr>
                    </apex:repeat> 
                    <tr><td colspan="8"><hr/></td></tr>     
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="8"><b>Partnumbers Match</b>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <apex:repeat value="{!QuoteWrapperList}" var="a" > 
                        <tr>
                            <td valign="top" width="20%"><a href="/{!a.Quote_Id}" target="_blank">{!a.Quote_Name}</a></td> 
                            <td valign="top" width="20%"><a href="/{!a.Quote_Id}" target="_blank">{!a.Quote_Num}</a></td> 
                            <td valign="top" width="20%"><a href="/{!a.Account_Id}" target="_blank">{!a.Account_Name}</a></td> 
                                <td valign="top" width="20%"><a href="/{!a.oppid}" target="_blank">{!a.oppname}</a></td>             
                            <td valign="top" width="20%">{!a.OPPrecordtype}</td> 
                            <td valign="top" width="20%">{!a.OPPtype}</td>             
                            <td valign="top" width="20%">    
                            <apex:outputText value="{0,date,dd'/'MM'/'yyyy}">
                            <apex:param value="{!a.CR_Date}"/>
                            </apex:outputText>         
                            </td>
                            <td valign="top" width="20%" align="center" color="Blue"><b>{!a.Count}</b> 
                            </td>                                                 
                        </tr>    
                    </apex:repeat>
                </table>
            </div>
        </apex:outputPanel>
```

> Error: SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field: Quote__c.Quoteopp_type__c Error is in expression
>   '{!PNSearch}' in component  in page searchpn:
>   Class.searchpn.PNSearch: line 108, column 1

I am used all the fields in soql query still it is saying the same error

Help me to resolve this issue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can Check this link it may help, I have also faced the same problem and it was solved with this question.

[Error message: SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/40379/error-message-sobject-row-was-retrieved-via-soql-without-querying-the-requested)

I guess the problem here is with

```
QuoteWrapper qw = new QuoteWrapper();
qw.Quote_Name = String.valueOf(aggr.get('QuoteName'));
qw.Quote_Id = String.valueOf(aggr.get('QuoteId'));
qw.Account_Name = String.valueOf(aggr.get('AccountName'));
qw.Account_Id = String.valueOf(aggr.get('AccountId'));
qw.Quote_Num = String.valueOf(aggr.get('QuoteNum'));
qw.Count = Integer.valueOf(aggr.get('nameCount'));
qw.CR_Date = Date.valueOf(aggr.get('CRDate'));
qw.oppid = String.valueOf(aggr.get('oppid'));
qw.OPPtype = String.valueOf(aggr.get('OPPtype'));
qw.OPPrecordtype = String.valueOf(aggr.get('OPPrecordtype'));
qw.oppname = String.valueOf(aggr.get('oppname'));
```

Here you are `aggr.get` where else in above lists you are accessing it directly with object.